# Parse CSV and append values to Excel sheet

Tags: excel, parsing, vba, csv

I'm looking for a way to parse a CSV and store values in a bidimensional array if possible.
From this array I want to append the values to a sheet in an order I desire.

For example I have columns A, B, C in the CSV and I want to place the values in the sheet like this:
Sheet Column C = B, Sheet Column D = A  etc..
You get the idea. Change the order of the columns. 
The CSV can have multiple rows.
All this via a macro.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I would recommand that you do manually all the operations, once, while recording a macro. It will produce a VB code that you will be able to modify/adapt.

To record a macro, you first need to enable the developper tab. Basically `File > Options > Customize Ribbon` and check Developper

Then go in the Developper tab, you'll see that you can Record a macro.
Click this button.

Do all the steps you described (those that you want to automate, via your macro).
Once you're done, click Stop recording.

Then click on `Macros > Modify`. It will open a window with the VB code of your macro.

You now have a solid base to start with, and you should be able to easily adapt it to your needs.

[How to enable the Developper Tab](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb608625.aspx)
[How to record a Macro with Excel](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/record-and-use-excel-macros-HA001054837.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I've tried that. I'm importing the file, but the problem is I can't manage to place the columns where I want. I saw that I can import as a ADO recordset but I think that's dependent on ADO drivers so that's not that convenient.

Comment: You can write a VB sub that will copy the data from the column B to the column C ; try something like : `Sheets("sheet1").Select
    Column("B").Copy
    Sheets("sheet2").Select
    Column(C).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste`

Comment: Thanks, I was trying to place everything before writing it to the sheet. I'll try this approach.